# How to detect heic image before upload in JavaScript on iOS11?

Tags: javascript, html, image-uploading, ios11

We have an image uploading application and we compress images on client side using an external [JavaScript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress.js) before uploading.

Now we have came across an issue specific to iOS11 when uploading image files having the extension of `.heif` or `.heic`.

As an example when we submit the form with `abc.heic` image, client side browser application crashes when trying to compress it through above library. So we want to restrict attaching `.heic` images to the image input.

Unfortunately we cannot identify (I think so) `.heic` images on server side, because we receive file name as `abc.jpg`on backend since iOS11 automatically convert `.heic` images into `jpg` images before uploading.

Therefore I want to detect it on client side, but when I check file MIME type on client side using below code, it returns `image/jpg` (actually I don't have an iPhone, so some other friend did it for me). So it looks like `.heic` image is already converted to `jpg` internally by iOS11 before I check MIME type. (But for some reason, those converted `jpg` files are not able to compress by this library)

```
$(document).on('change', '[id=uploading_file]', (evt) => {
    'use strict'
    const files = [...evt.target.files];
    var uploadingFile = files[0];
    var fileType = uploadingFile["type"]; // get file MIME type
    var ValidImageTypes = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/bmp"];

    if (jQuery.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes) >= 0) {
        // image compression code goes here.
    }
});
```

**Some alternative solution:**

I did some other alternative fix also to avoid attaching `.heic` images as below though it is not a guaranteed solution. Changed `accept="image/*"` to `accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/bmp"` , but it still shows `abc` image on file chooser.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as robust as using the mime type, but you *can* use the heic and/or heif extension to restrict which files can be selected.

For instance:

`<input type="file" accept=".heic">`